# The difference between the language of regular expressions and regular strings

Tags: regex, perl

I came up with the following CFG to express the language of all regular expressions.

```
S -> (S) | S* | S + S | SS | a | b
```

My question is is the above langauge regular?  I say no because the language of balanced parentheses is not regular, yet the language above includes the language of balanced parentheses.

Just wondering if anyone had a more elegant and definitive answer to this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on StackOverflow because it is about formal language classification. It might be on-topic at http://cs.stackexchange.com/ though.

Comment: Can this get moved there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the language of regular expressions and regular strings

Regular expression is regular automata, regular expression is expressed rules of a language which tells you that the given string is satisfying the rules or not, if it is satisfying then it is regular string (accepted by a regular language) because satisfied by a regular automata/ regular expression.
If not accepted by a regular expression then its not regular string for that regular language.

Exp English language has regular expression (regular automata) as grammer rules and accepted strings(grammatically correct sentences)  are regular strings.